# AngularJS or Backbone.js which one to use, consuming web service calls being the main requiremnet?

Tags: angularjs, web-services, backbone.js, web

The main requirement in my project is consumption of web service calls.
Which framework will be more suitable :

1. AngularJS
2. Backbone.js

Please help with proper reasoning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I could answer your question with the assumption that you are going to consume RESTful webservice.

Backbone:

Pros:

- It is very light weight
- It is very simple to learn

Cons:

1. Consuming RESTful webservices could be tricky if the service that you are consuming is not Resty (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#Applied_to_web_services)
2. Data binding could drive you nuts if you are kind of new to Java Script
3. This as such does not support modular development. We will have use any AMDfier like requirejs etc to make it modular.

Angular JS:

Pros:

1. It has out of the box support for RESful webservice integration (Eg: https://github.com/reflexdemon/ng-gulp/blob/master/src/app/customer/service/customer_service.js)
2. It has advanced data bindings that is supported by framework and makes developers life simple
3. There is very good documentation that is backed by Google and the community

Cons:

1. It is kind of heavy weight and would need time to bootstrap.
2. Might sound strange in first look and as you start coding you can admire the advantage on using Angular

Note: There are only my thoughts on these frameworks

Comment: Here is a nice article to do your research on these frameworks

https://www.airpair.com/js/javascript-framework-comparison